# Is it possible to do datatype inheritance in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

For example if I have two different records, but they share a handful of common fields, is there a way to make both records share a common base record? It seems like protocols only allow for declaring method signatures.

Comment: That two entities share some fields is not really sufficient reason to create an inheritance relationship between them.  Perhaps offer some example usage scenario.

Comment: For example, I'm using records to represent parsed SQL-queries. So I have records for SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, etc..  They share a few common properties, such as a 'string' property. When Im dealing with them using polymorphic functions, I want to be ensured they all have a few common properties.

Comment: Records are just fancy maps, so I'm not clear what it means to "ensure they all have a few common properties".  Why can't you just call `(:string a-record)`? Also, the set of keys a record might have is a different issue from behaviours that the concrete type can express.  What is the actual problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that is possible as of now.

`defrecord` is just a macro and you can check what it does by using `macroexpand`, something like:

```
(macroexpand '(defrecord User [Name Age]))
```

So if you want such record inheritance you probably need to implement a macro to do so. 
But I would not suggest that as inheritance is something that I try to avoid because it leads to complexity.

Answer (score 4):

You should be programming against an abstraction, not particular fields, i.e., use a protocol so the records can share a common interface. E.g., if all of your record types need to return a 'string' property, then create a protocol with a 'get-string' method and extend that to each record type.

```
(defprotocol SQL
  (get-string [t]))

(defrecord Thing [name f1 f2]
  SQL
  (get-string [t] (str name)))

(defrecord AnotherThing [name f1 f2 f3 f4 blah]
  SQL
  (get-string [t] (str name)))
```

If you find yourself creating the same implementation for a particular protocol method you can always 'defn-' (non-public function) the implementation and use it as the implementation in each record type.

Comment: what if I want to create a record that share some fields of another record ? like:   (defrecord a [ba bc])  (defrecord b [ba bc bd] .. how to deal such case ?